# How read only another file in excel vba without open it

Tags: vba, excel

I have two files. In the first i wrote a macro that takes as input the second file and open it to read its datas. The problem is that every time i launch the macro the second file open and i don't want that. I think the problem is this:

```
path = "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\example.xls"

Set openWb = Workbooks.Open(path)
```

The `Workbooks.Open(Path)` that open the file. How can i solve the problem? I need only take the example.xls file and read its data without open that file in summary. Thanks a lot